# JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, safari

i just switched to a mac today and i noticed the JSON.parse that works on other browsers, throws this error on safari.

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"
```

This is the JSON response from my PHP code

```
   {"dataPointsX": "[\"31 Jan\",\"01 Feb\",\"02 Feb\",\"03 Feb\",\"04 Feb\",\"05 Feb\",\"06 Feb\"]", "dataPointsY": "[\"0\",\"0\",\"7287\",\"24572\",\"30657\",\"27865\",\"0\"]", "dataPoints2Y": "[\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"]"}
```

This is my Javascript code

```
$.get('chartdata.php', async function (res) {
   console.log(res)
   var res = JSON.parse(res);
});
```

Please help

UPDATE

I have updated my PHP to echo this

```
{"dataPointsX":["31 Jan","01 Feb","02 Feb","03 Feb","04 Feb","05 Feb","06 Feb"],"dataPointsY":["0","0","7287","24572","30632","27820","0"],"dataPoints2Y":["0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]}
```

It works on chrome, safari still throwing this error

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"
```

Console.log(JSON.parse(res)) shows this on chrome

```
dataPoints2Y: (7) ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
dataPointsX: (7) ['31 Jan', '01 Feb', '02 Feb', '03 Feb', '04 Feb', '05 Feb', '06 Feb']
dataPointsY: (7) ['0', '0', '7287', '24572', '30489', '27744', '0']
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Why is the array wrapped in quotes? Looks like you are doing too much with json_encode() in the php

Comment: Backslashes need to be escaped in JSON: `\"` should be `\\"`.

Comment: @charlietfl Hello, thank you for your contribution. however, please check the updated question

Comment: @tromgy Hello, thanks for your contribution. however, please check my updated question

Comment: @tromgy The single backslashes are there to escape the quotes. No need for double backslash

Comment: Try using `$.getJSON()`. What is the error in Safari?

Comment: Try using a different name for the parse result, e.g instead of `var res = JSON.parse(res);` use `var result = JSON.parse(res);`.  Also, why is the function marked `async`? There is no any async code in it.

Comment: @tromgy removing async fixed it. thank you so much. i was trying to make the page load faster by using async loading for that script cause while i was testing on my VPS. it was slow, till i moved to my dedicated server, forgot to remove it. thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your PHP code is JSON encoding content that's already JSON encoded, maybe something like this:

```
$points = ['31 Jan', '01 Feb', '03 Feb'];
echo json_encode(['dataPointsX' => json_encode($points)]);
```

This yields the oddly quoted string:

```
{"dataPointsX":"[\"31 Jan\",\"01 Feb\",\"03 Feb\"]"}
```

You only want to call json_encode() once:

```
$points = ['31 Jan', '01 Feb', '03 Feb'];
echo json_encode(['dataPointsX' => $points]);
```

Comment: Hello, i appreciate your contribution. however, please check my updated question